# RoutedEventArgs.Source give me wrong value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="NewCommand_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>        
        <Menu Name="muMain" Margin="0,0,0,288">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem  Name="mnFileNew" Command="ApplicationCommands.New"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Button Name="btnNew" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="22,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439" Command="ApplicationCommands.New"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and code behind to test ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.Source:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void NewCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control bt = e.Source as Control;
        Console.WriteLine("New command triggered by " + bt.Name);
    }

}
```

If I click File-> New, the output is "New command triggered by **mnFileNew**", and then click the Button, the output is "New command triggered by **btnNew**". That's all good. But if I click File-> New again, the output is still "New command triggered by **btnNew**". Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Your exact question has been posted before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240699/wpf-applicationcommands-new-showing-incorrect-source-in-case-of-menuitem